# What are the different Commands to read the content in the IBM MQ files?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm very often facing an issue using the IBM MQ .
I see the "curdepth" parameter is showing some value in the queue, however when I try to see the content in the MQ using "strings" command, there is no data.
Can you please guide me what else I can do , are there alternate commands to read this ?

PS : I'm using 7.5.0.3 version of IBM MQ

Thanks
[image]

Comment: What are you running strings against?  You should be using a program to browse the queue not running strings on a file in the qmgrs file system.   Look at amqsbcg for example.   Many inexpensive options are available as well that have more features.

Comment: The current depth of 6 does not mean there are 6 messages available.  The current depth value includes both committed and uncommitted messages.  If you use a tool to browse the messages of a queue and it does not show you all 6 messages then that means the messages not shown are uncommitted (the putting application has not issued MQCMIT).  This is normal.

Comment: @Roger : Thanks for replying, actually that count is not changing since 2 days thats why I want to check what got stuck there, I believe application should have committed or removed those messages in this time frame

Comment: You can check if they are uncommitted by running `DIS QS(queue name) UNCOM`.  If there are no uncommitted messages it will display NO. If there are uncommitted messages,  depending on the version of MQ it will either display YES in older versions or the number of uncommitted messages in newer versions.   Messages may also not be written to the q file if the are not persistent.   My first comment still stands that you should not use the unix strings command as a reliable way to view messages on directly from the q file.